# cleveref and algorithm2e

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, cleveref, algorithm2e

I'm currently working on a document where I was using `algorithm`+`algorithmic` along with `cleveref`. With this everything worked perfectly.

Now I had to replace `algorithm`+`algorithmic` with `algorithm2e`. Ever since, I cannot `\cref` to the label in the `algorithm` environment. More explicitly, I can refer but `\cref` doesn't generate a text in front of the number (which is correct) of the algorithm.

I couldn't find any reference to `algorithm`'s packages in the `cleveref` documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: In addition to the fix in my answer, I suggest you contact the author of cleveref. He is very responsive to user requests, and will likely add support for algorithm2e if you explain to him what is needed.

Comment: For the record, Cleveref versions since 0.17.9 (released in 2011) support algorithm2e "out-of-the-box".

Comment: @Dror could you review the accepted answer? I think fixing the load order will be the superior solution in most cases.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to tell `cleveref` how you want to refer to the algorithms. Something like:

```
\crefname{algocf}{alg.}{algs.}
\Crefname{algocf}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. But I have another question. How did you know to choose for the type `algocf`? Where is it documented? Thanks a lot in any case!

Comment: From the log-file, without the above commands: `LaTeX Warning: cref  reference format for label type `algocf' undefined on input line 27.`

Answer (score 35):

You only need to load `algorithm2e` before `cleveref`.

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, in my opinion.

Comment: still, functions don't work.  and remaming algorithm into function doesn't work.

Comment: @caveman This seems to properly answer the question for most people. If you want something else I suggest you ask another question.

Comment: @xuhdev How did you came up with this solution? Is this something a user just has to know or could one of those packages be modified to warn the user about the wrong load order? (I recently had a package that nicely warned me that I need to load package X before package Y.)

Comment: @dreua - `cleveref` should almost always be loaded `last`.