# cref & algorithmic incorrect referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, cleveref, algorithmic

I tried to use the tipps in this post [cleveref and algorithm2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9800/cleveref-and-algorithm2e). But it does not lead to the correct referencing, what is done wrong here and how to i get cref running with algorithm?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}


%\input{Packages}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\crefname{algocf}{alg.}{algs.}
\Crefname{algocf}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}

\begin{document}
    \section{asdja}
\cref{alg:a} is a algorithm.
\ref{alg:a} is a glrotihm
\begin{algorithm}
    \label{alg:a}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State x
    \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{This is an algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that you didn't place the `\label` after the `\caption` command. If you use `\caption{This is an algorithm}\label{alg:a}`, if works fine. See [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/73317)

Comment: YES YES YES! It is working.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :-)

Comment: I forgot to say: you also need to use `algorithm` instead of `algocf` in the `\crefname` and `\Crefname` calls if you want them to be effective. The `algocf` counter is used by the `algorithm2e` package, which your sample code doesn't use. So, this was not completely a duplicate: half of the problem is the duplicate, the other half is what I said in this comment.

Comment: @frougon your advice really helped me, but the interesting thing is that I'm using algorithm2e and what helped me was the opposite of what you mentioned:

`\usepackage[ruled,vlined,portuguese]{algorithm2e} 
% ...
\usepackage{cleveref}
% ...
%\Crefname{algocf}{Algoritmo}{Algoritmos}   % <----- DOESN'T WORK!
\Crefname{algorithm}{Algoritmo}{Algoritmos} % <----- This works!
% ...
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 % ...
 \caption{How to write algorithms\label{algo:xxx}}
\end{algorithm}

Teste  \Cref{algo:xxx}.`

Comment: @igormcoelho It's quite possible that I mixed something up but AFAIK, you should put your `\label{algo:xxx}` *after* the `\caption{...}`, not inside its argument. ;)

Comment: @frougon yep, that was another good advice I took from you here... in fact, some years ago, the brazilian text guidelines (abnt) on latex, called ABNTex, required us to put \label inside \caption, otherwise count was incorrect, very strange thing. Then, I continued to do that for all these years. But I agree it's non-standard. Maybe even abntex has fixed this issue already, I don't know. Regarding the algorithm2e, my setup is quite crazy here, I'm using Pandoc and other stuff, so it could be another strange issue here as well. But it's solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @igormcoelho In fact, `\label` is something legal in the mandatory arg of `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, etc. and, after a quick look at the code for `\caption` in the LaTeX kernel, it seems to me that it can work there too (a quick test agrees). One learns every day. Good night!